# twitter API response : possibly_sensitive content

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

referring to this link  https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/700
Anybody observed possibly_sensitive boolean flag in twitter "search" apis.

Till now I was unable to see this flag, we need to have this data badly to avoid unwanted stuff to show up on our site.

Comment: Your link to .../discussions/700 is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Twitter currently adds the field for the search API. You may also note that the search API also does not return results for "popular" tweets, which could also expunge some of the more objectionable content (unless it had become popular). Love to hear other's input on this topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to achieve this, use filter:safe
Refer the API here : https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search